# Spring boot Project folder structure for rest client

Tags: spring-boot, rest-client, project-structure

I am working on a Springboot project where i need to consume lot of rest APIs.
The current project folder structure has a Controller, Model, Service, Dao and Util packages.

-The Util package has a Scheduler, that calls the Service module.
-The Service module will then call REST API of a different application and based on result will save data by calling DAO layer.

My doubt is "**The part where the service layer method calls rest api**". Do i need to place that code logic in a different class called RestClient.java ?
If yes then should that class be a part of service package itself or i need to create a different pacakge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constrained package structure. Actual structure will be driven by your requirement and directory structure is laid by build-tool / IDE.

but here is my recommendation in your `service` package you can have `provider` and`consumer` package from where `provider` packages can have services which will be called by your rest controllers and `consumers` can have service which will call other application services.

Or You can simple have `restclients` package like services from where you can define your `consumers` services to just separate out your package structure to distinguish your rest client services.